# phpmyadmin no longer showing table structures or data

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Using XAMPP for a locally hosted site for the past week, and today when i go to add new fields to some of the tables, clicking on Browse, Structure or Import shows nothing at all. The phpmyadmin layout is still there and I can click to other tables, but beneath the nav bar (browse, structure, SQL, etc) it shows nothing.

The data is still there as the website still works fine, and the main database page shows all the tables and how many rows etc.

Image of browse tab:

[image]

Image of database overview screen:

[image]

If I try to run any SQL commands from the SQL tab, i get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Transformations.php on line 363
```

I've no idea how to correct that and don't really want to be playing around with core code when I am so uncertain.

I've checked the memory limit in the *php.ini* and that is at 128mb, and the only thing mentioned in the *mysql_error.log* is that the buffer pool is small and could be increased (which unfortunately i don't really know anything about). The only thing that happened between working and not working was closing down my laptop and reopening a few hours later to continue working.

The only search results I've found when Googling have been about blank pages, or tables not being found in the database, neither of which really cover the issue i seem to be having.

Does anybody happen to know a fix/solution to this? Or is it going to need a complete reinstall of XAMPP perhaps?

Comment: Seems a file might have gotten corrupted? Can you redownload and setup xampp again?

Comment: That is indeed what i've had to do unfortunately. Thankfully it let me at least export all my databases first, and using Github kept all my files together so it was an easy transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line seems to be reinstalling XAMPP into a fresh directory and copying the databases back over. This has made pma workable again. No settings have been changed, no permissions change, just a fresh reinstall.